# How to set BackColor of a CheckBox in WPF

Tags: wpf

In WinForm we can set BackColor of a CheckBox

[image]

How do I do this in WPF? I try

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Background="Red"/>
```

but this only changes the rectangle border color

[image]

I also try

```
<CheckBox>
    <TextBlock Text="CheckBox" Background="Red"/>
</CheckBox>
```

but this only changes the text background color, not including the rectangle

[image]

=======

Thank you all for the solutions. I think the simplest way works for me :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the background color of a checkbox's content by binding in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478518/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-checkboxs-content-by-binding-in-wpf)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you experiment a little with panels you get there:

```
<Grid Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  <CheckBox Content="test" />
</Grid>
```

is pretty close to what you want.
Tried it myself ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
<Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox FlowDirection="RightToLeft" background="Red"
                          IsChecked="False" />
                <Border Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="20 0 0 0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Background="LightGray">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Style="{StaticResource RegularTextblock}"
                               Text="Checkbox1" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for little too much. Using Blend I made created a relevant style for the `CheckBox`.

The code was too big. So SO did not allow to display. Here is the pastie [link](http://pastie.org/10048854)

For the `Background` there is a grid `markGrid`. I added a `Background` and a `TemplateBinding` to force the `CheckBox` to change the colour. The drawback is the Path colour will be visible very faintly if the background is dark.

[image]